# What is "Territory" on itunes connect version summary page

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I'm reviewing the Version Summary page of my app in iTunes Connect and at the top there is a select list for Territory. The select list has only one item in it and it's "Peru".

Any idea what this is?

Example:
[image]

*update*
I've configured my app to only be available in the U.S. - This is why Peru is throwing me off.

*update 2* embarrassing mistake on my part. The checkbox layout was weird and I had checked off Peru and not United States:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The territory is the territory you are currently viewing the summary for. Mine has every country, US, Peru, China, etc. It allows you to switch the summary for the selected territory, so you can change the information displayed based upon what country the person trying to download your app is from.

Comment: Ok cool. Any idea why I would not have U.S. or China or anything but Peru?

Comment: My only suspicion would be that your App is set to only sell in Peru. Try going to "Rights and Pricing" and see what stores you have selected for your app to be sold in.

Comment: That was it. I'm an idiot. The checkbox positioning screwed me up: http://f.cl.ly/items/0X1p1E35113Y3l0q2D0F/Screen%20Shot%202011-11-28%20at%203.34.42%20PM.png

Comment: Lol, nice, glad we got it fixed :P

Comment: mine is selecting Norway. Even that all the check boxes are checked for all territories!